# 'pip3 --version' failing with a SyntaxError

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, setuptools

This all began when I set out to install the Requests library for Python 3 (I'm running on OSX Mavericks with Python 2.7.5 (installed by `brew install python`) and 3.4.2 (installed by `brew install python3`).  When I run `pip3 --version` (or anything related to the pip3 command) I see this:

```
$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification import SUBJ_ALT_NAME_SUPPORT
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ndg/httpsclient/ssl_peer_verification.py", line 17
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I run the Python 2.7.5 version I see this:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Just for sanity purposes Here is what when I see when I enter the interactive interpreters:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 17:52:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

A lot of the other answers related to updating pip3 suggest that I update pip3 with this commend `pip3 install --upgrade pip` which gives the same error, or I use `easy_install -U pip` but because of how brew sets up the Pythons, it only updates the Python 2.7.5 version (there is no `easy_install3`).  Any ideas?

Comment: Does `python3 \`which pip3\` --version` produce the same error?

Comment: Just tested, and yes.  I have also tried to run `brew uninstall python3` and reinstalled it.

Comment: Somehow, you've managed to install a Python 2.x version of something (possibly `requests`?) in your Python 3.x site-packages. There are some third-party packages that `pip` will use if they're available, and if one of them is available but broken, that can break `pip`.

Comment: Meanwhile, that `pip --version` is reporting what looks like a `pip` installed for Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7, not the new 2.7 you installed with Homebrew. The path is part of Apple's default site-packages but not Homebrew's, not to mention that it's Python 2.7.5 (which is what Mavericks comes with, but not what Homebrew has installed for quite a few months now). Which implies that you've already done something which has cross-contaminated your two Python 2.7s, so it wouldn't be surprising if whatever that was also screwed up your 3.4.

Comment: Oh, and the fact that `python` is compiled by clang 5, not clang 6, means you clearly didn't build it with Homebrew, you're running a binary someone else built a few months ago—in this case, most likely Apple. `which python` will probably say `/usr/bin/python`, not `/usr/local/bin/python`, right?

Comment: @abarnert your intuition is exactly correct. So if I dig around some shared folder, would it be possible to manually remove the requests library? or are we in "rebuild the OS territory"?

Comment: Not "rebuild the OS", but… rebuild the Python installs, maybe. Is it OK to wipe out all of your site-packages? And to uninstall and reinstall both Homebrew Pythons? And to not reinstall the Homebrew 2.7 and instead use Apple's 2.7 (and Homebrew's 3.4, still)? That would be reasonably simple, and should work.

Comment: just `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/*`?

Comment: Hold on, I just spotted something: One of the packages that `pip` will optionally use is `mercurial`. But `mercurial`'s 3.x support is still experimental, and it won't even install out of the box (at least with `pip`). Did you use some other installer to install `mercurial` (aka `hg`)? If so, does it have an uninstaller? That might rescue at least your 3.x with no more radical measures. (No promises, though.)

Comment: No, that will only uninstall packages you installed for 3.4 with `pip`, packages you installed in some other way end up in `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages`—and notice that the one that's actually failing (because it's actually 2.x code) is in the latter.

Comment: I found the culprit! it was a package called [`ndg-httpsclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ndg-httpsclient), running `sudo rm -rf ndg*` from the site-packages folder you gave me fixed it!

Comment: @abarnert, copy your comments into a answer and I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root problem is that you somehow got a Python 2.x-only package installed into your 3.x site-packages.

Underlying that, you've actually got two different Python 2.7 installations (Apple's and Homebrew's) crossed with each other, which may have something to do with how you got a 2.7 package into 3.x as well…

Anyway, the reason this is breaking `pip` is that `pip` has various optional dependencies that it tries to import if present, and some of them do the same, and so on, and ultimately, starting up `pip` is importing the [`ndg-httpsclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ndg-httpsclient) package.

I'm not sure how you got that package. A standard Homebrew 3.x looks in two extra site-packages directories (fire up `python3` then `import sys; print(sys.path)` to see all of the places it looks, both stdlib and site) beyond the one that `pip3` installs into.

In this case, you've somehow installed the 2.x version of `ndg-httpsclient` into `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/‌​python3.4/site-packages`.

Since you didn't install it with `pip`—and, more to the point, since you can't run `pip` in the first place—you can't just `pip uninstall` it. So:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/‌​python3.4/site-packages/ndg*
```

This could break some other packages that depend on it. Once you get things working, you can use `pip3 list` to see all the site packages you've installed and test them out. If you want to be paranoid, do something like this:

```
$ pip3 list > mypackages
$ rm -rf <each site-package directory>
$ brew uninstall python3
$ brew install python3
$ pip3 install -r mypackages
```

You might want to similarly clean up your Homebrew 2.7 (or just scrap it and only use Apple's—especially since I'm pretty sure you're running Apple's anyway), and the site-packages for the Apple 2.7 (but not Apple's Python itself, of course, because you can't uninstall that).