# pip3 on ubuntu 12.04 - syntax error

Tags: python, pip, syntax-error

I have installed pip3 on Ubuntu 12.04 by typing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools

sudo easy_install3 pip
```

As result, I get:

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Processing pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3.2 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

But when I type:

```
pip3 --version
```

then I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 856
    http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, why I have this syntax error? I get that also when I am trying to install some package with pip3.

Note:
I have the following python versions installed:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ python3 --version
Python 3.2.3
```

Best regards,

Comment: What Python version are you currently running?

Comment: 2.7.3. I will add it also to the question. thx

Comment: Python 2.7 requires you to use the regular `pip` command, `pip3` is specifically for Python 3

Comment: I have also installed python3 (see the end of my question).

Comment: Try installing the python module using the following command `python3 -m pip install <module-name>`

Comment: still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried removing pip3 and installing it through [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) ? I usually install pip with that. I think your pip3 script is using python2 to run.

Comment: It looks as if the version of pip you have installed does not support Python 3.2. The line that is failing `u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s'` is using the unicode prefix `u''`. This is supported by Python 3.3+, but not Python 3.2.

Comment: @Alasdair: ok now I have python 3.4.5 installed. but still the same error.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with more information. If you're still getting the same error, then it looks like you're still running Python 3.2 and not 3.4.

Comment: Have you tried using `get-pip` as @ThuYeinTun suggests?

Comment: yes, but executing python get-pip.py gives me the following error: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: @ThuYeinTun : I removed pip3 and execute python get-pip.py. but it installed pip with version pip 9.0.1 and when I type pip3 --version into shell then it says that the command is not found

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 --version
```

Comment: thx but when I try to install python3-pip then I get this: E: Unable to locate package python3-pip

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26519222/7901843 . Looks like your problem.